# description list : grouping <dt>and its "child" <dd>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

HTML5 has nice tags for description. w3.org gives [the following example](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dd-element):

```
<dl>
 <dt><dfn>happiness</dfn></dt>
 <dd class="pronunciation">/'hæ p. nes/</dd>
 <dd class="part-of-speech"><i><abbr>n.</abbr></i></dd>
 <dd>The state of being happy.</dd>
 <dd>Good fortune; success. <q>Oh <b>happiness</b>! It worked!</q></dd>
 <dt><dfn>rejoice</dfn></dt>
 <dd class="pronunciation">/ri jois'/</dd>
 <dd><i class="part-of-speech"><abbr>v.intr.</abbr></i> To be delighted oneself.</dd>
 <dd><i class="part-of-speech"><abbr>v.tr.</abbr></i> To cause one to be delighted.</dd>
</dl>
```

, describing the contexts in which `<dd>` element can be used as "After `dt` or `dd` elements inside `dl` elements".

This strikes me (, a complete beginner) as strange: shouldn't these `dd` elements somewhat *belong* to the `dt` which they are describing? Because `<dt>happiness</dt>` and `<dd> The state of being happy</dd>` are definitely related to each other, one describing another? With `dt` and `dd` aligning without structure, the only way to tell what a specific `dd` describes is to find the last `dt`. I'd feel much safer with something like (`di` for each item)

```
<dl>
  <di>
    <dt><dfn>hapiness</dfn></dt>
    <dd class="pronunciation">/'hæ p. nes/</dd>
    <dd>The state of being happy</dd>
  </di>
</dl>
```

Although I'm tempted to ask "Am I right worrying this?", my questions are:

- What are the conventions when using `dl` in html5? Do they group `<dt>` and `<dd>` in some way or another, or is it just fine as it is?
- If I am to group them (like above, but using the standard tags), is there any tag I can use semantically?

Comment: `<dl>` is HTML 4.1 (possibly earlier), not HTML 5; but, otherwise, no, there's no grouping other than the 'implicit' (all `<dd>` elements belong to the previous `<dt>`).

Comment: Note that you can also have a run of `<dt>` elements. The `<dd>` elements that follow "belong" to all those `<dt>` elements, not just the last preceding one. Many people have desired a `<di>` element but it adds no new semantics, so it's not really a HTML issue.

Comment: @DavidThomas - `<dl>` has been a part of HTML since before HTML 2.0 was published.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know - a `<dd>` is the definition for its immediate preceding `<dt>`.
Technically you wouldn't have more than one `<dd>` per `<dt>`.
Do something like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>happiness</dt>
  <dd>
    <span class="pronunciation">/'hæ p. nes/</span>
    <span class="definition">The state of being happy</span>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

and then style the spans accordingly.

EDIT:

My apologies, as David Thomas pointed out, it is okay to have more than one `<dd>` per `<dt>` (http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element).
I think the main idea I have here is that I still think it would be neater, and easier to style if the `<dd>` was split up into sections as above.

Comment: No, you can have one or more `<dd>` elements related to any given `<dt>` element (and I think you meant 'preceding' rather than 'superior').

Comment: True - I meant preceding :) - Also, you're right - You can have more than one <dd> tag - I've just looked it up. However, I still think it's neater and easier to style with the <dd> divided up into sections.

Answer (score 2):

The `dl` element has been part of HTML since the early days (formally since HTML 2.0), and it has always been vaguely defined. Nominally called “definition lists”, it has been interpreted as being generally a “description list” or really just “association list”. It associates “names” in `dt` elements with the content of the `dd` elements after it, up to the next `dt`. If there are several consecutive `dt` elements, they are all associated with the following `dd` elements.

The association (grouping) is defined, in the [description of `dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), but it is “purely semantic”; it has no implications as such, and you cannot even make it explicit using some intermediate markup, since the `dl` syntax allows only `dt` and `dd` as children (and `script`, but that doesn’t help).

The conclusions depend on what you expect the association to be used for. If you really need a container for a group, just use some other markup that lets you throw in the markup you need. If you expect the association to be relevant to assistive software, you might consider using ARIA attributes, as suggested by the following example on [an MDN page on ARIA:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute)

```
<dl>
    <dt id="anathema">anthema</dt>
    <dd role="definition" aria-labelledby="anathema">a ban or curse solemnly pronounced
                                                     by ecclesiastical authority
                                                     and accompanied by excommunication</dd>
    <dd role="definition" aria-labelledby="anathema">a vigorous denunciation : cursor</dd>

    <dt id="homily">homily</dt>
    <dd role="definition" aria-labelledby="homily">a usually short sermon</dd>
    <dd role="definition" aria-labelledby="homily">a lecture or discourse on or of a moral theme</dd>
</dl>
```

However, the practical usefulness of such added markup is very small. Most software ignores it. Besides, if the list has been written properly, the associations between “names” and “values” are evident enough without such markup.